# How to remove Eclipse user short cut keys?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I create a user shortcut key in the Eclipse. [image: My shortcut key next key in multiple time]

Now I hit the restore defaults option. It wouldn't remove user keys and Still available user keys.

Is there any other way available to remove user keys?

Comment: For me, when I hit the *Restore Defaults* button, all custom key bindings get removed. Also custom copies of bindings (such as *Next tab* in your screenshot) get removed. I don't understand why that doesn't work for you. I'm using Eclipse  2020-06 (4.16.0). What version are you using?

Comment: @Lii Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)

Answer (score 0):

For me, when I hit the *Restore Defaults* button, all custom key bindings get removed. Also custom copies of bindings (such as *Next tab* in your screenshot) get removed. I don't understand why that doesn't work for you.

But your can try this:

Select all the copies of *Next tab* one by one and hit the *Unbind Command* for binding copies, or  button *Restore Command* for original bindings.